# Login to my facebook app on facebook comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have on my webpage the code for comments like this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=111285118965654";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  <fb:comments href="MY_WEB_URL" num_posts="2" width="470"></fb:comments>
```

Comments works fine. I've already have on the head:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="MY_FBID"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="MY_APPID"/>
```

With these options, i have moderation tool working, but i can't delete any post from users. I've read (i don't know if it's true) that if someone login to facebook with my application, and adding on FB.login a scope with parameter "publish_stream", then, my application will have a way to delete any comment. Well, the problem is that i don't know how to force a user to login to my facebook app before making a comment.

Sorry if my explanation is not good or is wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check to see if user is logged in and has given permission, if so render comment box if not then render a login button for user to reAuth or Auth with your app.

Let me find a few code snippets.

---

NOTE: I just tested this with my app using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments i was unable to delete any post but my own, or my pages own.  Other users are still hide, ban or boast.

Comment: So you mean that there is no way to delete other post. Ok, so i was wrong. Thank you so much!